# ftp_get fails but no error is reported

Tags: php, ftp

I can't download a file from the FTP server to my local computer. I keep on getting false from `ftp_get`

```
// define variables
$folder_path = "Applications/MAMP/htdocs/infoscreen/PVdata";
$local_file = fopen ("newpv.csv",'w');
$server_file = "tlxesb@pv-systems.dk-171206100007";

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ftp_get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php) takes a path to a local path as the second `$local_file` argument, not a file handle:

```
$local_file = "newpv.csv";
ftp_get($conn_id, "newpv.csv", $server_file, FTP_BINARY);
```

---

Or maybe you wanted to use [`ftp_fget`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fget.php), which takes a handle:

```
$handle = fopen("newpv.csv", 'w');
ftp_fget($conn_id, $handle, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)
```

Though it makes sense only, if you want to do something more with the file, otherwise use the simple `ftp_put`.

Also, make sure you close the handle, once the upload finishes:

```
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Thanks i needed to use `ftp_fget`